# Pre-Commit Hook for PMD, Checkstyle and Findbug

Tags: webhooks, bitbucket-server

I have got a requirement to install Pre-Commit hook in Atlassian Stash(v3.11.6) for PMD, Checkstyle and Findbug to prevent commit, if the code changes does not meet the requirements. Could you guide me on where to get the hook and how to proceed further?

Comment: I have to do something similar ... have you found any way.

Comment: not yet found anything.. :(

Comment: https://github.com/gherynos/pre-commit-java